# TableView rendering is very slow with html content image in Objective c

Tags: ios

I have a chatting App, sender can send html content with multiple image from web.In App on chating page have tableview that have 2 TableCell.one for sender another for receiver. table cell have textView for message display.
i show html content in textView but it take time when html content have many images.Any solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate thread to handle displaying html in Cell

Comment: you mean i should use GCD?